# How do single-phase inverters know if they're in sync with the grid after they're in parallel?

Tags: inverter, signal-processing, power-grid

How can one inverter, once its output is already in parallel with the grid, measure the phase difference between the grid and itself?

Any current or the variation in the current flowing on its output could happen due to the load on the grid, once its impedance varies erratically (different things being turned on and off, not to mention equipment that changes its impedance by itself).

Also, a variation in its output current could also happen due to a voltage mismatch rather than a phase mismatch.

So, how does it measure that? More specifically: Is there a simple solution for it that doesn't require computing?

I've come to a solution, but its quite complicated (although completely feasible): An inverter that, after first synchronizing and paralleling to the grid, works like an FM voltage source, and uses something like a lock-in amplifier to measure variations in the output current that happen with a known frequency (due to the FM modulation).

In this FM voltage source, the carrier signal would have the same frequency as the grid (like 60 Hz) and a modulating signal of much lower frequency and low amplitude (causing the carrier signal to vary just a little bit around 60 Hz, like +-0.01Hz, and with a low frequency, like 3 Hz).

Considering that the inverter and the grid are in phase at the very "middle point" of the modulation cycle, then the output current will have have 2 variation cycles per modulation cycle: It will have a minimum each time the modulation is at the middle point and a maximum each time the modulation is at a extremum.

Note that these current variation cycles I'm talking about are the variations caused by the effects of this modulation, and once they happen at a known and low frequency (much lower than the grid), you can measure the current and use something like a lock-in ampifier to amplify only these variations and filter out the rest.

The filtered measurements can then tell how much it is deviating from the grid. If, for example, the inverter is not in phase with the grid at the middle point but in another point inside the modulation cycle, the 2 current "variation cycles" that happen at each modulation cycle will have different amplitudes and lengths (one will be shorter and lower than the other).

And if they're not in phase at any point, then there will be a single current variation cycle per modulation cycle: A minimum when the inverter is closer to be in phase with the grid and a maximum when it's farther from being in phase.

The inverter can also use that to deduce if the grid is down (as it would suddenly be no longer in phase in any point of the modulation, without first deviating from the middle point).

But I find this way quite complicated. Is there any other, simpler way?

Comment: [Phase Locked Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLL)

Comment: Just because your current has an angle alpha against the grid doesn’t mean the voltage has been shifted. The grid is strong compared to your inverter and the voltage is the reference and it stays the same.

Comment: But what if the other supply is not the grid but another identical inverter, in a way that if any of them deviating they would shift the mean voltage?

Comment: Also, the inverter also needs to detect if the grid was disconnected from it. If it was just measuring its own output voltage as a reference, disconnecting the grid would make it keep measuring its own reference all the time